# syntax error: identifier 'TEXTMETRICA' in D3DX10Core

Tags: c++, directx-11, direct3d11, directx-10, direct3d10

I Have Just Started Learning D3D and my code was working all fine till i implemented the D3D Shader Compiler Stuff to my code.

I am Using the tutorial on [DirectXTutorials](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=11-4-5). if i just copy paste the code from there on to a new project, the program compiles fine.

However i have put my code in different classes unlike the tutorial. It is giving me error when i try to compile my saying: Syntax Error: "TextMetrica" (Compiling Direct3DRenderer.cpp).

Here is the Direct3DRenderer File:

```
#include "Window.h"
#include "Direct3DRenderer.h"
#include "Vertex.h"

Renderer::Renderer(HWND hw)
{
    OutputDebugString("Direct3D Initializing\n");

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;
    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));         // ZERO OUT SCD
    scd.BufferCount = 1;                                    // HOW MANY BACKBUFFERS WE WANT
    scd.OutputWindow = hw;                                  // HANDLE TO THE OUTPUT WINDOW
    scd.Windowed = true;                                    // SHOULD WINDOW BE IN WINDOWED MODE BY DEFAULT
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;     // BUFFER FORMAT
    scd.BufferDesc.Width =  800;                            // BUFFER WIDTH
    scd.BufferDesc.Height = 600;                            // BUFFER HEIGHT
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;      // USE SWAP CHAIN AS OUTPUT TARGET
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                               // MSAA COUNT
    scd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;     // FLAGS

    if (D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
        NULL,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &scd,
        &swapchain,
        &dev,
        NULL,
        &context
    ) == SEVERITY_SUCCESS)
    {
        OutputDebugString("SUCCESS\n");
        // Get The Address of BackBuffer
        ID3D11Texture2D* pbuffer;
        swapchain->GetBuffer(0, _uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)& pbuffer);

        // Create a Render Target COM Object from the buffer
        dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pbuffer, NULL, &RenderTarget);
        pbuffer->Release();

        // Set Our RenderTarget as the back buffer
        context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &RenderTarget, NULL);

        // Create Our Viewport
        viewport.Height = 800;
        viewport.Width = 600;
        viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
        viewport.TopLeftY = 0;

        context->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

        InitPipeline();
        InitGraphics();

    }
    else
    {
        OutputDebugString("ERROR\n");
    }
}
Renderer::~Renderer()
{
    OutputDebugString("Direct3D Cleanup Phase Started.\n");

    swapchain->SetFullscreenState(FALSE, NULL);
    swapchain->Release();
    context->Release();
    RenderTarget->Release();
    VS->Release();
    PS->Release();
    dev->Release();

    OutputDebugString("Direct3D Cleanup Phase Completed.\n");
}

void Renderer::InitPipeline()
{
    // Compile Shaders from file
    D3DX11CompileFromFile("shaders.shader", 0, 0, "VShader", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &compiled_vs, 0, 0);
    D3DX11CompileFromFile("shaders.shader", 0, 0, "PShader", "ps_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &compiled_ps, 0, 0);

    // Convert Compiled Shaders to COM Shader Objects
    dev->CreateVertexShader(compiled_vs->GetBufferPointer(), compiled_vs->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &VS);
    dev->CreatePixelShader(compiled_ps->GetBufferPointer(), compiled_ps->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &PS);

    // Sets the shaders to the device / Activates the shader
    context->VSSetShader(VS, 0, 0);
    context->PSSetShader(PS, 0, 0);

    // Create the Input Layout
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC VertexElementDesc[] = {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
    };

    dev->CreateInputLayout(VertexElementDesc, 2, compiled_vs->GetBufferPointer(), compiled_vs->GetBufferSize(), &InputLayout);
    context->IASetInputLayout(InputLayout);
}

void Renderer::InitGraphics() {
    // Create Buffer so we can duplicate data from system memory to graphics memory
    ZeroMemory(&VBufferDesc, sizeof(VBufferDesc));

    VBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 3;
    VBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D10_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    VBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    VBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;

    dev->CreateBuffer(&VBufferDesc, NULL, &VBuffer);

    Vertex OurVertices[] =
    {
        {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,      D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)},
        {0.45f, -0.5, 0.0f,     D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)},
        {-0.45f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)}
    };

    // we need to map to avoid issues
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mapRes;

    context->Map(VBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &mapRes);
    memcpy(mapRes.pData, OurVertices, sizeof(OurVertices));
    context->Unmap(VBuffer, NULL);
}

void Renderer::RenderFrame()
{
    context->ClearRenderTargetView(RenderTarget, D3DXCOLOR(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0));

    // We can do the rendering here

    UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    UINT offset = 0;
    context->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &VBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    context->Draw(3, 0);

    // Swap Buffer
    swapchain->Present(0, 0);

}
```

The TEXTMETRICA Identifier error is actually in D3DX10Core.h. i have peeked in the definition and that file seems to be giving me the error. this identifier's definition should be in gdi file.

I have added the include paths and lib paths to the directx(June 2010) SDK and also tried specifying d3dx10.lib, d3dx11.lib, d3d11.lib in the project's addition dependency on the all configurations setting. I am new so i dont know what i am doing wrong. if any more code is required please comment about it.

Comment: @AdrianMole - it's perfectly OK to use the `A` functions and structs in a Unicode build.  It's just that `TEXTMETRIC` without an explicit `W` or `A` qualifier will result in either TEXTMETRICW or TEXTMETRICA being assumed via typedef.

Comment: The likely solution is that the OP just needs to `#include <windows.h>` before all other header files.  Not the same as the `"Window.h"` thing referenced at the top of the OP's current file.

Comment: @selbie the window.h has the windows.h include in it.

Comment: If you can provide an [mcve], I can solve this for you.

Comment: @selbie Indeed - my mistake (too much hot sunshine).

Comment: @selbie :P ok so i was using a modified version of windows with tonnes of defines for removing useless stuff and that was messing with it. This is the file i was using [Modified window from chilliengine](https://github.com/planetchili/hw3d/blob/master/hw3d/ChiliWin.h). i will make sure not to use those imports.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that most of the Internet tutorials for DirectX 11 are a bit outdated. In particular, you don't actually *need* the legacy DirectX SDK. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/), [this one](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/), and [this one](https://walbourn.github.io/the-zombie-directx-sdk/).

If using VS 2015/2017/2019 and you still want to use the legacy DirectX SDK, then you have to set up the include/lib paths in a particular way or you'll get problems. The details on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-#using-directx-sdk-projects-with-visual-studio).

> You are welcome to use these older tutorials with some caveats, but you should also take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) for some more 'modern' tutorials.

**UPDATE:** One other option for using the legacy D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11 utility libraries is to use the [Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX) NuGet package. This removes many of the quirks around mixing it with the modern Windows SDK and Visual C++ toolsets. It also includes the redistributable binaries with a simple side-by-side license instead of having to use legacy DXSETUP. That said, the binaries themselves are still quite ancient, have known bugs, and are no longer supported, so [YMMV](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ymmv). See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/).

Comment: Thanks for this. I have the DirectX Sdk june 2010 downloaded and it includes all that i should need. I will read the other blog posts if i need to. i have the libs and stuff all setup already and have rendered a triangle for now to check if it works. do give me docs for tutorials as the one that i was using requires a premium membership to continue forward. I ill definitely use the DirectX Tool Kit guide that you provided.